# SQL Server - build up query using table valued function

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables structure:
**tblMapping**

```
map_id   | name  | parent_id
1          A       0
2          B       1
3          C       2
4          D       2
5          E       4
```

**tblEditableContent**

```
id   | map_id   | desc_id   | isExcluded
1      1          0           0
2      4          0           1
```

In this table, `tblEditableContent`, `desc_id=0` means that all elements below the given map_id (all its children) are allowed to be displayed and `desc_id=1` means that the node itself is selected.
I also have a table valued function (mapping) that will build up the node for a given map_id, similar to the result below:

for `select * from dbo.mapping(1)`

```
map_id   | name
1          A
2          B
3          C 
4          D 
5          E
```

for `select * from dbo.mapping(4)`

```
map_id   | name
4          D
5          E
```

Now, for the task and requirement.
I try to create the following result:

```
map_id   | name   | desc_id   | isExcluded
1          A        0           0
2          B        0           0
3          C        0           0
```

In the same time, if we change the value of `desc_id` in `tblEditableContent` from 0 to 1, then the output should be:

```
map_id   | name   | desc_id   | isExcluded
1          A        0           0
2          B        0           0
3          C        0           0
5          E        0           0
```

And here is what I have tried out until now:

```
select ca.map_id, ca.name, ec.desc_id, ec.isExcluded from tblEditableContent ec
CROSS APPLY (
    Select * From dbo.mapping(ec.map_id)
) ca 
where ec.isExcluded = 0
order by ca.map_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like below:

```
select 
    ec.* 
from tblEditableContent ec
join
(
select 
ca.map_id as map_id,
MAX(ec.isExcluded) as isExcluded
from  tblEditableContent ec
    OUTER APPLY 
        (
        Select map_id from dbo.mapping(ec.map_id) where ec.desc_id =0 or (ec.desc_id =1 and map_id=ec.map_id)
        ) ca 
group by  ca.map_id
)ca
on ca.isExcluded=0 and ec.map_id=ca.map_id
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work.. From where are you getting the ca.map_id within the outer apply?

Comment: And also, the JOIN will return only the map_id's found in the tblEditableContent.. regardless of the outer apply..

Comment: @rosuandreimihai please try now.